# Lazy load + polling using Angular.js and php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I was working on a piece where I needed to perform lazy loading of images.
Now, I've a new requirement where there will be a batch process running on the server which will pull images at regular interval from DB.
These images then need to be added to the photos array on the scope and should be shown on the UI without refreshing the page (polling or pub-sub sorta stuff).
Polling sorta thing. I'm using Angular.js and php. Any suggestions?

Comment: Node.js would be something for you.

Comment: $http call from directive would be better..using $intervals

Comment: Hi @pankajparkar thanks for the response, my only concern is that I've the whole array of images on the rootScope.. the new images will definetly be added to this array of images with a $http call but will it be parsed to be shown on UI as the DOM had already loaded the first set of images when the page was loaded the first time... how would it sense that the images array has been updated and the new images are to be shown too?? Sorry but I'm kinda getting tangled.. newbie to Angular.js :/

Answer (score 0):

You could work with timeouts in javascript, grabbing new images from your php api.
This would be quite easy to code and would be your polling sorta thing :)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` can be used for polling. Example:

```
function initializePoll(repeatedFunction, timeSpan) {
    setInterval(repeatedFunction, timeSpan);
}
```

where `repeatedFunction` is the `function` you want to repeat, `timeSpan` is the time interval you want to elapse between two calls. Naturally, your `repeatedFunction` should send a request to the server, get the image and change what is needed to be changed in the UI.

Comment: You got me right there.. I thought of implementing it in similar fashion but the hook here is adding those new set of images on UI without refreshing the page....!! So it's gonna be a div which has a lotta images and you can scroll and view them and if there are any new images being pulled, they should get added in the original array of images and show up without page refresh.